# How discover what scope/scope object is causing repaints of a view?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

We have a route view that is specified via:

```
{ when: "/level", view: "views/levels.html", controller: "LevelController" }
```

In that view, I've put a call to a method that simply logs that it has been called:

```
<!-- Call to the method -->
{{wasPainted()}}
```

The method:

```
$scope.isPainted = function() { console.log("Was painted"); };
```

This method prints 10 times!

I want to find what is causing this and then pull that object out of the scope until it's done and then set it once so the view is only painted/changed once.

How do I find the object(s) that's causing this?

**EDIT:**

Even if my view has only the below call to the method, it still gets called over 10 times!

```
{{wasPainted()}}
```

Comment: post your view html and we can tell you...

Comment: @epitka it happens even with a blank view!

Comment: This is normal. Read about digest cycle.

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling function within a view, it will execute as many times as there are digest cycles. It is normal..